# Is it wrong to close as "not a real question" if someone's actually taken the time to post a legitimate answer?

Tags: discussion

Given that the question was perhaps overly brief and/or under-researched:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468024/in-what-way-are-page-tables-remotely-like-mathematical-functions

The fact that it was closed as "not a real question" *after* I answered it means that as far as reputation goes, that answer was a waste of time. If others can't figure out what the question is or think it's not up to snuff, that's fine, but if they don't get it closed *before* someone posts a legitimate answer, I wish they'd leave it alone.

Or am I looking at this the wrong way? I didn't find the question fit the characterization given.

"It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form"

Comment: people can still upvote your answer even if the question is closed

Comment: @Ephraim: Sure, but a question like that will likely end up deleted, which will take the reputation with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How would someone in the future benefit from this question?  Is it enlightening at all, or would someone encountering the question (and its answer) be better off simply reading a good reference on the subject?

In fact, your answer merely refers the user to an off-site reference.

If you've posted a satisfactory answer to the OP's question, is there any compelling reason to keep the question  open?

Comment: So they can mark it as the answer?

Comment: They can do that anyway, even if the question is closed.

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding. Thanks.